# Problem with pointers of pointer ** char

Tags: c, pointers, char

I have a

```
char** color;
```

I need to make a copy of the value of

```
*color;
```

Because I need to pass *color to a function but the value will be modified and I cannot have the original value to be modified.

How would you do that?

The whole code would look like this

```
Function1(char** color)
{
  Function2(char * color);
  return;
}
```

I have to mention that the pointers in function1 and 2 are used as a return value.

Comment: I take it that "Char**" should be "char**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1

```
functionTwo( const char* color )
{
   //do what u want
}

functionOne( char** color )
{
    functionTwo( *color );
}
```

or version two

```
functionTwo( const char* color )
{
   //do what u want
}

functionOne( char** color )
{
    char* cpMyPrecious = strdup( *color );

    functionTwo( cpMyPrecious );

    free( cpMyPreciuos );
}
```

hth

Mario

Comment: I don't think that works if I need to modify it in the function 2.

Comment: Then you go with version 2, drop the const from fucntionTwo, and do not free the cpMyPresious . Use it as you think - and once you are done, free it!

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest using strncpy() for duplicating the value. the string you are pointing at is in the memory just once, making another pointer to it doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have `strdup()` available (it's not part of the standard library), you would do something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
...
void function1(char **color)
{
  char *colorDup = malloc(strlen(*color) + 1);
  if (colorDup)
  {
    strcpy(colorDup, *color);
    function2(colorDup);
    /* 
    ** do other stuff with now-modified colorDup here
    */
    free(colorDup);
  }
}
```